# compare two different sized arrays and get a 1 separate array of matched values and 1 of locations

Tags: arrays, matlab, signal-processing

How to compare two different sized arrays and get a separate array of matched values locations and separate array for matched values.

I have two arrays of different sizes

```
 Ylocknew = [0    1.0000   -4.3000    5.0000   -4.2000 7.0000   -7.4000    8.0000    1.0000    4.0000]

 Ypos         = [1     5     7     8   4]
```

I want to compare two arrays and get another array which contains similar values of Ypos and Ylocknew and also other array which contains index values of matched points.

**Code:**

```
 Ypos(end:numel(Ylocknew))=inf
 R_common =Ylocknew(Ylocknew==Ypos);
 I = find(Ylocknew==Ypos);
```

**Expected Output Values:**

I need 2 new array

```
Yposlocknew = [1 5 7 8 4]
Yposloc = [2 4 6 8 10]
```

**Used Approach :**

```
RST_intersection = (intersect(Ylocknew,Ypos))

Output for similar values :

RST_intersection = [   1     5     7     8]
```

For Indicies(I have tried) :

```
  RST_intersection = find(intersect(Ylocknew,Ypos))
```

**Result is (That is wrong )**

```
 RST_intersection =[  1     2     3     4]
```

I am trying to do this but it is giving me an empty matrix of size 1*0.

Any fast and easy way to do this without using loop if possible to speed up the process as I have a lot of values.

Comment: This is the result that i am getting with ismember but its wrong ismember is replicating values I have tried this command also. and Why not this is the reason that last end 1 is not matching I have to match Ypos with Ylocknew and get matrix without repetition means Ypos has values and i need locations at which these values are avaiable in same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need here is [**`intersect`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/intersect.html) with the `stable` flag.

```
[Yposlocknew, Yposloc] = intersect(Ylocknew,Ypos,'stable');
```

---

`find(intersect(Ylocknew,Ypos))` will definitely give you `[1 2 3 4]` since  all elements of `intersect(Ylocknew,Ypos)` are non-zero.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot it worked now fine .. Great answer and thank for ur help and time upvoted and accepted.